# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "get-votes at path "_id" for model "Data"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

I am getting this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed
>   for value "get-votes at path "_id" for model "Data"

This is my model:

```
const dataSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  votes: Number,
});
```

This is my route:

```
router.get('/most-votes', (req, res, next) => {
  return Data.find({}, function(error, data) {
    let dataMap = {};

    data.forEach(e => dataMap[data._id] = e);
    res.send(dataMap);
  });
});
```

However, I still get the above message. Can someone help please?

EDIT: I have checked the above "possible duplicate", however, it is not duplicate. I am using `.find()`.

Comment: The code you are posting is not the problem. Presumably you have a different route which actually has a `findById()` method in it. Possibly `/post/:id` or `/user/:id` or whatever the "master" route here is and you thought you have a `/post/get-votes` ( or whatever ) route, but that is being passed in as a `param` value. So the error is most likely where a `findById()` is in the code, but the cause is route params.

Comment: But I do have a `get-votes` route as well, which is a separate one.

Comment: You "think" you have a separate route, but that route is not being hit because it's passing into the "parameters" of the root on that controller path. Add a `console.log('hi')` in the route you think is being hit and see that it is not. You are hitting the one with the `findById` in it.

Comment: I see, so what should I do? Can you please write answer, I will gladly accept it. Thanks man.

Comment: The linked answers ( and I just added something more directly related to your problem ) have about the same information I have given and should guide you. Besides you did not even post the code for the route which is actually causing the problem.

Comment: Ok, will check more, thanks.